# How do I create a placeHolder in the BasicTextField?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

I have a certain `TextField` where I needed to specify my padings.
[image]
When there is no text in it, I want to output something like "It's empty here".

Unfortunately, `BasicTextField` does not allow me to add placeHolder as a modifier. Perhaps you know how to fix this situation? Or you can fix the standard paddings on a regular `TextField`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `decorationBox` parameter you can add a `TextFieldDefaults.OutlinedTextFieldDecorationBox` where you can define the `placeholder`.

Something like:

```
    var enabled by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
    val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }

    BasicTextField(
        value = text,
        onValueChange = { text = it },
        singleLine = singleLine,
        interactionSource = interactionSource,
        decorationBox = @Composable { innerTextField ->
            TextFieldDefaults.OutlinedTextFieldDecorationBox(
                value = text,
                innerTextField = innerTextField,
                enabled = enabled,
                singleLine = singleLine,
                visualTransformation = VisualTransformation.None,
                interactionSource = interactionSource,
                placeholder =  { Text("placeholder") }
            )
        }
    )
```

Comment: I've read the documentation, but I still don't understand what the modifier accepts interactionSource. Could you explain to me?